# How to filter date and time in sql

Tags: php, sql

I would like to ask about how to filter by from default date until input date. query :

```
SELECT date as Date, COUNT(*) as Transaction, SUM(status=0) as Success 
FROM transaction_201504 
WHERE date  BETWEEN '2015-03-23' AND LIKE '%" .$searchterm. "%';
```

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to not use `LIKE` when using `BETWEEN`. You must put the exact value.

```
WHERE date  BETWEEN '2015-03-23' AND '$searchterm';
```

where `$searchterm` has a format of `yyyy-mm-dd` (e.g. "2015-03-25")

Answer (score 0):

since your date is in the format YY-M-D (and not D-M-YY / M-D-YY ) you can use string comparison like:

```
SELECT date as Date, COUNT(*) as Transaction, SUM(status=0) as Success 
FROM transaction_201504 
WHERE date  >='2015-03-23' AND date  <= $searchterm;
```

Hope it help a bit.